# Google direction API wrong result

Tags: google-maps

I have an issue with Google API result which giving a wrong point when I comparing the same value in my application as well as google map. Seems google map is correct and I wonder why the API gives me wrong value. I am attaching both results here.

Any help?

Google Map result
[image]

My Application Result
[image]

Comment: Well, both are possible routes. Aren't they? Google Maps choose the route by using an algorithm, so the route won't stay the same. May be it detected traffic on the usual route.

Comment: Adding to that, in one search there is additional information like "Suite #112", allowing Google to know where in the building one happens to be. None of the addresses are quite the same.

Comment: Just curious to know that how come both result shows different when I search the same direction at same time.

Comment: The location it shows is far from the destination and it can't be based on traffic as it always shows wrong all time. Any other suggestions please